# Facebook OAuth Stuck

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, oauth, passport.js

I've been trying to solve this for a day now but I can't find my mistake. I've been working with JavaScript for a while on the client side and started working through a book. Unfortunately facebook seems to have altered their oauth method a bit since then (for example username seems to be deprecated). So my problem is this. Either if im not signed in to facebook yet, I get redireced to fb. I sign in, but get stuck on its site.
If however I am locked in, my browser just keeps on loading for a minute or 2 then tells me the auth key has already been used. I hoped that maybe you could help me. My environment file looks like this

(development.js)

```
module.exports = {
//Development configuration options
db              : 'mongodb://localhost/mean-book',
sessionSecret   : 'developmentSessionSecret',
facebook        : {
    clientId        : '*************',
    clientSecret    : '************************',
    callbackURL     : 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/facebook/callback'
}
};
```

on the developers.facebook page i have set my app domain to localhost, and the site url to http://localhost:3000/oauth/facebook/callback. I've tried numerous variations there. nothing helped so far. This is what my strategy looks like

facebook.js

```
var passport        = require('passport'),
url             = require('url'),
FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy,
config          = require('../config'),
users           = require('../../app/controllers/users.server.controller');

module.exports = function(){
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID            : config.facebook.clientId,
        clientSecret        : config.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL         : config.facebook.callbackURL,
        profileFields       : ['id','email', 'name', 'displayName', 'gender', 'profileUrl'],
        passReqToCallback   : true
    },
    function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){
        var providerData            = profile._json;
        providerData.accessToken    = accessToken;
        providerData.refreshToken   = refreshToken;
        console.log('------PROFILE-----');
        console.log(profile);
        console.log('------END PROFILE-------')
        var providerUserProfile     =  {
            firstName   : profile.name.givenName,
            lastName    : profile.name.familyName,
            fullName    : profile.displayName,
            username    : profile.id,
            email       : profile.emails[0].value,
            provider    : 'facebook',
            providerId  : profile.id,
            providerData: providerData
        };
        console.log('---------------');
        console.log(providerUserProfile);
        console.log('---------------')
        users.saveOAuthUserProfile(req, providerUserProfile, done);
    }));
};
```

My passport config looks like this

(passport.js)

```
var passport    = require('passport'),
    mongoose    = require('mongoose');

    module.exports = function(){
        var User = mongoose.model('User');

        passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
            done(null, user.id);
        });

        passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
            User.findOne({
                _id: id
            }, '-password -salt', function(err, user){
                done(err, user);
            });
        });

        require('./strategies/local.js')();
        require('./strategies/facebook.js')();
    };
```

and finally my routes use this method

```
exports.saveOAuthUserProfile = function(req, profile, done){
    User.findOne({
        provider    : profile.provider,
        providerId  : profile.providerId 
    }, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            return done(err);
        } else {
            if(!user){
                var possibleUsername = profile.username || ((profile.email) ? profile.email.split('@')[0] : '');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks first if you made it through all this code to help. I'd really appreciate it, since im pretty lost here. Thanks again and

Greetings Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to call `done` function if fb user authorized successfully

```
exports.saveOAuthUserProfile = function(req, profile, done){
    User.findOne({
        provider    : profile.provider,
        providerId  : profile.providerId 
    }, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            return done(err);
        } else {
            if(!user){
                user.possibleUsername = profile.username || ((profile.email) ? profile.email.split('@')[0] : '');
            }
            done(null, user);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah. Found that out too and was about to post it. Sometimes the answer can be pretty simple :). Thanks alot